# how to get unique value from Arraylist java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

im using Contains method to evaluate customer1 set has cust object, but its keep on adding the same object(its not checking any duplicate)

```
 `List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();`
    `customers.add(new Customer(1, "A"));`
    `customers.add(new Customer(2, "B"));`
    `customers.add(new Customer(1, "B"));`
    `customers.add(new Customer(1, "C"));`
    `customers.add(new Customer(2, "A"));`
    `customers.add(new Customer(2, "B"));`
    `customers.add(new Customer(1, "A"));`
    `customers.add(new Customer(2, "C"));`
    `Set<Customer> customers1 = new HashSet<Customer>();`
    `for(Customer cust: customers) {`
        `if(!customers1.contains(cust)) {`
         `   customers1.add(cust);`
        `}`
    `}`
```

Expected Output:

`[Customer{id=1, name='A'},` 
`Customer{id=1, name='B'},` 
`Customer{id=1, name='C'},` 
`Customer{id=2, name='A'},` 
`Customer{id=2, name='B'}]`

Comment: Show your `Customer` class.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java

Answer (score 0):

contains() internally calls equals() method to check for the identity so you have to overide equals() along with hashcode() method to check for Identity.

Below link will help you:

[Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could just do

```
Set<Customer> customers1 = new HashSet<>(customers);
```

but your issue is mostlikely because your not overriding equals, hashcode